# .NET Parallel Tasks gets slow after a while

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, windows-server-2012

I have an application which processes a tiff image by performing ICR recognition and cutting some fields of tiff file based on coordinates, then it saves each image piece into the database. We need to process a lot of images per minute, so we need to have various threads processing images at the same time.

The environment where the application runs is a Windows Server 2012 DataCenter edition with 256GB of RAM, 2 Intel Xeon processors of 18 cores each one and 7 SSD drives in a RAID 0 configuration or something like that.

Because of that, we expect to run a maximum of 28 threads in parallel. To do that, we are using TPL Library to start parallel tasks. This is a sample of code:

```
private void btnIniciar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {    
    if (managerTokensCancelacion != null)
        managerTokensCancelacion.Dispose();

    managerTokensCancelacion = new CancellationTokenSource();
    tokenCancelacion = managerTokensCancelacion.Token;

    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < 28; cnt++) {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(myAction(cnt+1), tokenCancelacion);
    }

}

private Action myAction(int numThread) {
    return () => {
        try {
            while (true) {
                (new BusinessClass()).splitAndReadImage(numThread)); 
                tokenCancelacion.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException ex) {
            Console.WriteLine("Cancelled process");
        }
    };
}
```

We have a BusinessClass which does all the logic, but the basic function is to search in the database for an image (we have our concurrency mechanism to avoid having various threads processing the same image). We dispose all the objects in order to avoid memory leaks.

The problem is, the application runs fine for the first one or two minutes, depending of how many processes i start. It uses all the cores as you can see in the picture (this is not the production server, but it has 8 cores).

But, when i process near 400 images, it slows down and the tasks probably run sequentially using only one core.

There's something that i'm doing wrong in my code? As i mentioned before, we don't have memory leak problems, it runs using the same memory and not increasing continuously, we dispose all our objects on each iteration, but suddenly it slows down and stops using all the available cores. Maybe is something about Windows Server? Or a bug of TPL library? Database queries run fine on each iteration.

Comment: What is your `splitAndReadImage` doing? Reading from a database?

Comment: Yes. The flow is the next:
1. Gets an image from the database
2. When it finds it, i have an array of coordinates previously loaded in my application
3. I iterate through this array cutting each piece
4. I save each piece in the database
5. Finally, i update a field where i got the complete image, indicating that i have processed it without problems.

Comment: I suspect your code is synchronized which doesn't allow other thread to access then same resource? So only one thread is used and thus only one core. To stop us from guessing and give answers, you need to post relevant code of `splitAndReadImage`. If it touches database, you're better off with asynchronous database calls.

Comment: We need to see the main core logic in your flow.

Comment: I have debugged a lot my code and the queries doesn't get slower, the query times were almost the same on all times.

Comment: We handle the concurrency at database level. We use Oracle and through a stored procedure we lock a row using FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED, and while the row is locked, we insert a record in a lock table. The main query has a NOT EXISTS with this lock table. excluding all those records that are locked. Finally when it exits from the SP the row is unlocked. 
I wouldn't like to post the code because it has like 2000 lines.

Comment: I would recommend first querying the database and then starting up threads and give them the images. Also the threads should return the result you need to be saved in the DB. And then you handle the insert to DB outside.

Comment: @OscarCalderon How did you solve the issue ? I have the same problem in my code. The code run fast in the first 10 minutes, but after it become very slow. I try to insert millions of lines in my code.

Comment: Sorry folk @THEHOLYSPIRIT, it's been a long time and I haven't touched .NET since then. I think I wasn't able to, just went for another approach with a different technology.

Comment: Okay. Wich tech @OscarCalderon

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to try JetBrains dotTrace profiler in "Timeline" mode. https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/help/Analyzing_Concurrency_Profiling_Results_Timeline_.html

It will show you pretty accurate why your application slows down - it happens because of garbage collecting or because of IO operation of whatever.